# "A big glass" vs. "The big glass"

Tags: definite-article, word-order, indefinite-article, modifiers

I was reading articles online and found this:

> When a modifier appears between the article and the noun, the
> subsequent article will continue to be indefinite:
>
> ```
> "I'd like a big glass of orange juice, please," John said.
> "I put a big glass of juice on the counter already," Sheila replied.
> ```
>
> Source:
> http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/determiners/determiners.htm

My question is that **"can we rephrase this sentence:"**

> "I put **a** big glass of juice on the counter already," Sheila replied

**Something like this:**

> "I put **the** big glass of juice on the counter already," Sheila replied

**If not then please let me know below sentence is correct or not?**

> I have seen the big house in our town.

Comment: Fersher. But with the definite article you are talking about a specific glass or a house which you expect your hearer to know about.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you explained to me but could you please explain this (When a modifier appears between the article and the noun, the subsequent article will continue to be indefinite...........).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The website you got this from is pointing out something very peculiar. It first gives this example:

> "I'd like **a** glass of orange juice, please," John said.
> "I put **the** glass of juice on the counter already," Sheila replied.

Sheila is referring a particular glass of juice – the one she put on the counter. Therefore, she switches from ***a** glass* to ***the** glass*.

However, when they add a modifier:

> "I'd like a **big** glass of orange juice, please," John said.
> "I put a **big** glass of juice on the counter already," Sheila replied.

Why, in this case, did Sheila say "*a* big glass" instead of "*the* big glass"? Because (this website claims):

> *When a modifier appears between the article and the noun, the subsequent article will continue to be indefinite*.

#### I think this is **bad advice**.

In the first example, Sheila could say  *a glass of juice*, even without the modifier. In fact, I think that version sounds better:

> "I'd like **a** glass of orange juice, please," John said.
> "I put **a** glass of juice on the counter already," Sheila replied.

Also, I don't see how the presence of a modifier determines which articles should be used. Consider:

> John ordered **a** dish. I cooked **the** dish for him.
>
> John ordered **a** succulent dish. I cooked **the** succulent dish for him.

I didn't switch to an indefinite article just because I added the word *succulent.*

Either I'm missing what this website is trying to say, or else the website is trying to create a "rule" that shouldn't be a rule.

Comment: +1.  I think what the website is trying to say is: "If you have an indefinite article followed by a noun, just adding a modifier does not change the article-  if it was indefinite before the modifier was added it will remain so (*continue*) after the addition."  I suspect that this "rule" stems from an attempt by English learners to say that by adding a modifier I am now talking about a *specific* something and so why shouldn't I change to *the*.

Comment: Great, it made me clear. This was the answer I was looking for. And Jim also made a very good point.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the definite article "the" in front of a name  gives a strong connotation to the name in question.

The big glass / the house in our town,  would indicate that specific glass or house which you want to put in evidence for some reason.

Usage is important especially for non-native speakers which always find this issue confusing. The below link might help.

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you explained to me but could you please explain this (When a modifier appears between the article and the noun, the subsequent article will continue to be indefinite...........)?

Comment: Pls make an example to illustrate your point.

Comment: Please check my question agian. I have explained everything and I understand what you are trying to explain about articles but I already know them but when I read something unexpected so I landed here. Please check my question, I have given the link and pasted what I was reading there.

Comment: I put the big glass... would not be appropriate

Comment: I have seen  the big house in our town, is grammatically correct. The use of "the" again is to be seen within  the  context.

Comment: Thanks, could you please give me any reason with some examples, if 'the big glass' is not correct then how 'the big house' became correct?

Comment: I said  that "the big house" is grammatically correct. The context from which the sentence is taken will tell you if "the" or "a" is the correct article to use. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Okay, I understood now. thanks, it was helpful. I appreciate your help.